# How do get value in returned tuple

Tags: rust

I am having trouble with the returned value from Aave's [Lending Pool V2](https://etherscan.io/address/0x7d2768dE32b0b80b7a3454c06BdAc94A69DDc7A9#readProxyContract) function `getUserConfiguration()` which returns a single tuple value ([value]), I can't seem to get this to work

err

```
InvalidOutputType("Expected `U256`, got Tuple([Uint(0)])")'
```

My code

```
let user_config:(U256,) = aave_lending_pool_contract.query("getUserConfiguration", *borrower, None, web3::contract::Options::default(), None).await.unwrap();
```

I have tried `user_config:(Vec<U256>,)` also but no luck. Any ideas?

==========

update, tried this

```
let (user_config_result) = aave_lending_pool_contract.query("getUserConfiguration", *borrower, None, web3::contract::Options::default(), None).await.unwrap(); 
let user_config = user_config_result.0;
println!("user config is {:?}", user_config);
```

still got the err

```
617 | ...   let (user_config_result) = aave_lending_pool_contract.query("getUserConfiguration", *borrower, None, web3::contract::Options::default(), None).await.unwrap(); 
    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
618 | ...   let user_config = user_config_result.0;
    |                         ------------------ type must be known at this point
```

Comment: let (user_config) = aave_lending_pool_contract.query("getUserConfiguration", *borrower, None, web3::contract::Options::default(), None).await.unwrap();

Comment: that doesnt work... still got err InvalidOutputType("Expected `U256`, got Tuple([Uint(0)])")'

Comment: do not annotate the type of user_config, otherwise, it force to expected U256.

Comment: I wasn't. It is defaulted as U256 because I was using it later as U256.

Comment: that doesn’t work, get the return triple first, then take the u256 value out of the tuple

Comment: I tried what you said but the compiler says "type must be known at this point", it needs a type :(

Comment: can you place the codes and the complete error message

Comment: I have updated the code and err in the post. thanks!

Comment: What is the query() method look like? do you have definition?
it seems to me the return type is inferred,  does it return ([T])? or (T)?

Comment: it is the standard query function in web3 rs lib https://docs.rs/web3/latest/web3/contract/struct.Contract.html#method.query

Answer (score 0):

the error does tell that need to annotate the type to U256, try below

````
let user_config_result: U256 = aave_lending_pool_contract
.query("getUserConfiguration", *borrower, None, web3::contract::Options::default(), None)
.await.unwrap();```
````